# Google Visualizations Pie Chart PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter, google-visualization

I have to make a pie chart that will display this data:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['Type', 'Amount'],
           ['Option1',   11],
           ['Option2',     6],
         ]);
```

I'm using Codeigniter to make queries and create an array which is fed into the JS like this:

```
    function drawChart(){
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $type_array_json; ?>);

        var options = {
            title: 'Type',
            legend: {position: "bottom"},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('type_chart'));
        
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I'm querying the data like this:

```
function get_chart_data($ID = '', $start_date = '', $end_date = '')
        {
            if (!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date))
            {           
                $this->db->select("Option1 and Option2 as Type, COUNT(ID) as Amount", FALSE); // This line is the problem
                $this->db->from('TABLE');
                populate_where($this->db, 'ID', $ID, $ID);
                
                $this->db->group_by("DATALABEL");
                $this->db->order_by("DATASORT ASC");
                
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $this->_create_report_array($query->result_array());
            }
```

Option1 and Option2 are both fields in a record that can be 1 or 0, and I need to compare the total amount of Option1=1 vs Option2=1.

How can I make the resulting array the same as the example one, so that the graph will display the 2 options in the first column and the values for them in the second?

Please help me

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. _"I need to compare"_ is not a problem description - how have you tried comparing them, what failed and what do you expect as a result?

Comment: What are you expecting `Option1 and Option2 as Type` in the column list of a SELECT statement to achieve in the first place? Pretty sure that won’t do what you think it would.

Comment: @CBroe I need to populate the array like the example one, so I'm trying to query the field names in the first column and the values in the second. I don't really understand the SQL aspect of it, that's why I need help

Comment: You are not querying any “names”, `Option1` in the column list of the SELECT statement, will get the the _value_ of that column, not its name. You should probably just `SUM()` up the values of those columns (the 1 values will accumulate, and the 0 values won’t be “counted” by summing up.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model to only fetch data from the database and pass the data to a controller for formatting.

**MODEL**

```
public function option_model()
      {   
         $this->db->select('option, COUNT(*) as frequency');
         $this->db->group_by('label'); 
         $this->db->order_by('frequency', 'desc');
         $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
         return $query->result();    
      }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function option_controller(){
        $result = $this->Database_model->option_model();
        $array = array();
        $cols = array();
        $rows = array();
        $cols[] = array("id"=>"","label"=>"Option1","pattern"=>"","type"=>"string");
        $cols[] = array("id"=>"","label"=>"Count","pattern"=>"","type"=>"number");  

        foreach ($result as $object) {
            $rows[] = array("c"=>array(array("v"=>(string)$object->label),array("v"=>(int)$object->frequency)));
          }
        $array = array("cols"=>$cols,"rows"=>$rows);
    
        return json_encode($array);
        }
```